# Core data inserts blocks UI

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm running a URLSession data task to download some data asynchronously - and after that inserting it to core data (can be around 2000 items). Saving data to the db freezes the UI. Seen other posts on this. What am I missing?

```
 self?.api.getData(param1, param2: id,  success: { (data) -> Void in
         let myData = JSON(data!)["Data"]
         self?.insertDataToDb(myData){result in ...
```

...

```
    func insertDataToDb(_ data: JSON, success: @escaping SuccessClosure, failure: @escaping FailureClosure){

            let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
            privateMOC.parent = context
            privateMOC.perform {
                self.insertJSONdata(data[Keys.FirstData])
                do {
                    try privateMOC.save()
                    self.context.performAndWait {
                        do {
                            try self.context.save()
                            success()
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            failure(error)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you sure about _saving to core data_ freezes the UI not the _retrieving data from the network_? Show the implementation of `getData(...` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the UI in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateUI()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this led me in the right direction. Sorry for blaming Core Data, Credits @nayem, it was actually the JSON-parser which blocked the UI, before inserting the data...